# Exponentional format in xls Perl Script

Tags: perl, dbi

I have a Perl Script which I am running to generate xls file. Please note I don't have Excel Module Installed for Perl. The Perl Script is running a SQL, and I am generating a XLS file. One of the fields is 14 digits, and it gets displayed in Exponential Form. Is there a way to display the entire number?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DBI;
unlink("D:\\Report.xls");

my $host = '';
my $user = '';
my $pwd = '';

my $driver = "Oracle";
$dsn = "DBI:$driver:host=$host;service_name=abc;port=1234";
$dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, "$user", "$pwd") || die "connect failed: ";
$sth = $dbh->prepare("Select  to_char(DTIME,'DD-MON-YY hh24:mi:ss') as DTIME, VID From Table");

$sth->execute;
$msg = "Up";
$Count = 0;
$Output = "";
$Temp="";
$tbl = "<TABLE border=1  bordercolor=orange cellspacing=0 cellpadding=1>";
$tblhd = "<TR><TH>DTIME</TH><TH>VID</TH></TR>";

while(  my $ref = $sth->fetchrow_hashref() ) {
        $Count++; 
        $Temp = "<TR><TD align=left rowspan=1 valign=top height=50>$ref->{'DTIME'}</TD><TD align=center rowspan=1 valign=top height=50 width=200>$ref->{'VID'}</TD></TR>";
        $Output = "$Output$Temp";
        $Temp="";
}
$dbh->disconnect;

$Output="$tbl$tblhd$Output</TABLE>";

my $filename1 = 'D:\\Report.xls';
open(my $fh1, '>', $filename1) or die "Could not open file '$filename1' $!";
print $fh1 "$Output";
close $fh1;

if ( $Count > 0 )
{
$msg = $Output;
}

print "\nMessage: $msg";
print "\nStatistic: $Count";
```

The VID Column shows up in Exponentional Format For Eg. 2.0232E=13. Is there a way to display the complete number?

Comment: It is 14 digits in the database table, however when I open in Excel it shows up in Exponential Form. On the perl script I added a width, however that did not make any difference.

Comment: It displays all the values in that column. 20322010578519164220126339723062201463123839222016654416333220122821093082201391588421022012462730291220203319431912201635234335022016164750211220165041033862201121617815122019578023186220074854782852201640570532822020331944

Comment: What shows up in the file that you write?

Comment: It shows up in exponential format. 2.0232E=13

Comment: If you try `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper($ref)`, what do you get?